# Column to comma seperated value partition by ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

i have on sql server 2008 table like

```
 EmployeeCertificationHistoryId EmployeeCertificationID EmployeeID  CertificationID CertificationDate
1   244 2192    1   2/15/2006
2   185 2058    87  4/10/2010
3   245 2240    102 8/11/2013
4   246 2249    104 11/23/2005
5   247 2221    101 6/12/2013
6   248 2238    84  NULL
7   245 2240    102 8/11/2013
8   249 2240    102 8/4/2013
10  253 2175    84  6/19/2013
11  254 2239    105 2/5/2011
12  255 2239    111 11/22/2012
9   96  1468    92  12/6/2010
13  256 2239    110 11/22/2012
```

i need to comma seperate certificationid per employeeid.
for eg. for 2239=>105,111,110

i have written a query but it is giving all certificate id in one column. my query is

```
SELECT STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + CAST(C.CertificationID AS VARCHAR(100))
FROM tbl_PM_EmployeeCertificationMatrixHistory C
ORDER BY c.CertificationID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
GO
```

i just need employeeid and certificationid.but i am unable to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need a correlated subquery and a list of employees.  The following gets the list of employees from the same table but you might have another table with this information:

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(C.CertificationID AS VARCHAR(100))
              FROM tbl_PM_EmployeeCertificationMatrixHistory C
              where c.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
              ORDER BY c.CertificationID
              FOR XML PATH('')
             ),1, 1,'') AS CSV
from (select distinct EmployeeID
      from tbl_PM_EmployeeCertificationMatrixHistory
     ) e;
```

Comment: Isn't it extra processing to do a whole extra `SELECT DISTINCT` subquery?

Comment: Actually, it is extra processing to do the `distinct` in the outer query.  This produces the distinct list first and then the subquery for each separate employee.  Putting the distinct outside probably results in running the subquery for each row of the table, and then doing the distinct afterwards.

Comment: Makes sense!  I checked out the execution plans after I commented and I see that now. http://puu.sh/6DJxk.png Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add EmployeeID to the query as well as a `WHERE` and `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.EmployeeID, STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + CAST(C.CertificationID AS VARCHAR(100))
FROM tbl_PM_EmployeeCertificationMatrixHistory C
WHERE C.EmployeeID = A.EmployeeID
ORDER BY c.CertificationID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
FROM tbl_PM_EmployeeCertificationMatrixHistory A
GO
```

If you want to return only `DISTINCT` values in the the CSV list, add `GROUP BY c.CertificationID` above the `ORDER BY`